# clion: fixing an undefined identifier

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I have inherited a C project using make and I am no expert in either cmake or Clion

I have a file a.c

```
#define A 1
#include "b.c"
```

b.c

```
int i=A*3; //<=== undefined identifier A here in Clion
```

This compiles fine with simple CMake file

```
add_library(myLib a.c)
```

How do I tell Clion that identifier `A` is defined in a.c when editing b.c

**Note**

VSCode seems a bit "smarter": editing both a.c and b.c at the same time will have b.c use the identifier defined in a.c. Still, I would appreciate a CLion solution, if any.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem (perhaps) but if you include a source file into another source file, then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are most certainly right but unfortunately this is not something I programmed and I would like to change it as little as I can. The original developer did this so he/she could easily generate different targets with various versions of a.c while keeping the same b.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This identifier is not defined for `b.c`, obviously. And it is rather strange to include `.c` file.

What you probably want is `a.h` file with following contents:

```
#ifndef _A_H
#define _A_H

#define A 1

#endif // _A_H
```

And then use `#include "a.h"` in both `a.c` and `b.c`.

Comment: This does not really provide an answer to my question, but, yes, I agree: this what the original developer should have done (you would be surprised, he is from a well-known shop :)). Thus, +1

Comment: Ah, you wanted IDE to provide identifier info even if it is not related for the current translation unit? Well, "real" IDEs like Clion, MSVC and KDevelop are trying hard to specifically not provide info for symbols that aren't defined in the current TU. For instance, even `printf` would be undefined if `<stdio.h>` isn't included. On the contrary, VS Code is just an advanced text editor, and it doesn't fully understand code semantics, so it just shows whatever info it has.

Comment: Yes. That is right. I take your comment as an answer (that it is not doable with CLion) and then award it to you. Thanks